# Have to recreate random loss of power

Tags: crash, hardware-failure, intel-core-i7

**note:** With loss of power I mean a crash without a BSOD or any form of warning or errors. No freezes, nothing. It just turns off in an instant.

So, for a little over a year now, I have been having the most random cases crashing. My PC will simply lose its power and boom, that's it. There are no other issues. I can restart my PC instantaniously and it doesn't run slow or anything. (I simply press the power button after it had crashed and voila; It's up and running again)

These are the steps taken (in mimial detail) so far:

- Built new PC: 750W psu, intel 4790K, ASUS Maximus VII Hero (motherboard), 8gb Kingston value RAM, AMD Radeon 7900 (also called the 260x) This is where the crashes started.
- Replaced the RAM and my SSD. The RAM is now 4x4gb Kingston Savage X RAM. (it was only 2x4GB at first, though)
- Took out a harddrive with SMART errors
- Replaced the videocard with the AMD HD Radeon 290X
- Replaced the PSU with a 1000W alternative(borrowed)
- Replaced the PSU with a 750W alternative with better scores (gold label as well)
- Detached the GPU, plugged monitors into the on-board gpu, only to find out 
  this caused (can't reproduce!) severe graphical distortion and sometimes refusing to boot. (again: Can't reproduce it all of a sudden!)
- Ran the intel diagnostics tool(full pass)
- Stresstested my entire PC (no results)
- Stresstested CPU (no results)
- Stresstested GPU (no results)
- Let memtest86+ run for 2 days to gain over 100 passes on my RAM
- Checked the motherboard for any weird stuff (burnt out thingies and such) and found nothing
- Contacted both intel and asus support, also both having no idea what has caused the issue (though both hinted at the other, so that's useful...)

The fact is, that I cannot debug this issue properly without being able te recreate it. **I need to recreate it.**

See, hardware swapping only gets you *so* far. The issue is that my PC crashes so incredibly randomly, it can live without crashing for up to 9 months. Yes, 9 months. Swapping hardware is a game of chance. As it went well for over 9 months after swapping my SSD and RAM (I believe it was after that, at least), I had thought it must've been my old RAM. There was also a point where I had thought it was my old videocard.

Well, safely to say, my old build (by now my entire pc has been replaced except for the cpu and mobo) is now running smoothly for someone else as a second hand pc.

If anybody has *any* idea at all as to how I could force a crash, I could at least debug it after the hardware swap.

My mind is exploding and I'm running out of... well... brain. Please help ._.

**Added to answer comments:**
Power fluctuations shouldn't be happening as I have a power stabilising unit between my pc and the wall. Besides, I live in a first world country, electricity generally doesn't really fluctuate too much here. Also, the PSU has been replaced. The chances of the PSU creating them are quite low. The graphical glitch we had discovered also disproves it being a power problem.

It's not the temperatures either. My pc runs like a fridge. My idle cpu temp is ~28 celsius and my GPU (right now it isn't in there) ~42. Under load my CPU hits ~45 and my GPU ~60. My CPU hits ~70 after about 1,5 - 2 hours of stresstesting.

**Update:**
I have been furmark benching my intel HD chipset for 60 minutes now. It's not showing any signs of instability as of yet. The only instability found so far is my mind dying of how it only hits 8fps

**Update 2:**
<strike>I have been stresstesting my CPU + the onboard chipset (intel HD 4600) for 45 minutes now and my pc still claims the CPU is only 37 degrees C. Does this sound healthy to anyone? I know I'm cooling well but I can't be cooling so well it only hits 37 degrees C with 100% load, right?</strike>
It would seem I wasn't patient enough. My cpu has now hit 50c.

**Update 3:**
Intel could not reproduce the problem I was facing. Because of this they're sending me a new CPU. This should either solve the issue entirely or prove that the motherboard is the part at fault. However, Intel clearly has reason to think it is indeed their CPU causing the problems.

Comment: Just what do mean 'lose power' and how do you restart it? Describe what happens.

Comment: PSU, Mainboard and heat are the likely candidates. Since you already swapped the PSU, the chance of that being the problem is low. Might be a Mainboard issue or a fan getting stuck randomly.

Comment: Could be A/C power fluctuations... I would put it in a small UPS.

Comment: Updated my question to answer these comments. - @Peter I am afraid it might indeed be the motherboard. However, as long as I can't prove it's the motherboard and not the CPU, sending it to asus would be risky as they ask for ~300 bucks if there was no issue found. I can buy 2 high-end motherboards for that money...

Comment: Turning off in an instant is not a Crash, its is sudden power loss to the motherboard for whatever reason, if you do not know what is causing it how can you re-create it.....this is a guessing game.

Comment: @Moab Yes, and that's why I need help on figuring out how to re-create it. Everything has been excluded except for the cpu, the motherboard and the RAM. Some people assure me it's the CPU while others assure me it's the mobo. A select few thinks it has to do with the RAM. If I could only find something to force trigger the crash, I could start swapping these parts and figure out which one causes the disruption. I need help finding this way.

Comment: There may not be a way. The problem is so broad, with so many things that could be causing it. For all you know, you could have a short in your USB controller that controls your Keyboard that only happens when `n` number of keys are pressed at the same time. One of your VRMs could be faulty. You may have lost the silicon lottery. Your neighbor could be starting the microwave a bit too often.

Comment: So you're saying I should just cough up a new motherboard and hope the problem goes away? (I assume replacing the motherboard would remove suspicion of things like usb ports and others)

Comment: You could examine the solder connections for the main and CPU power connectors, in case something looks awry there. Also, you could push the M/B in various places to see if slight flexing reproduces the problem. Finally, do you happen to have been using the same custom cable for the power all through this, if applicable?

Comment: @AndrewMorton The technicians looked at that. All seems to be perfectly good. - What do you mean a custom cable for the power? I had used the cable of my old PSU, and have recently replaced it with the cable of my new PSU.  - If I flex my motherboard like this, would it not create static and short-ciruit it? I really don't trust touching my motherboard while the pc is running. (There is an issue of the motherboard being slightly loose in the bottom left corner, by the way, but I don't believe that would matter. The little back-pin isn't holding as tight as it should)

Comment: @Babydead Flexing the motherboard will not create static discharges. You can use an anti-static wriststrap (they have a 1MΩ resistor incorporated for safety) if you are concerned. You only need to bend it a miilimeter or so The idea is to find out if there is a broken trace on the motherboard. As for the custom power leads, some people like to use them for the visible part; you would know if you had one.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you for that information. I will go and try this =) So, if this small motion would make a crash happen, it would mean one of the traces isn't making good contact? Like a broken audio cable only working in specific positions? - **update:** I have done as youév asked. No crash. It's actually been running surprisingly stable since I've put my GPU in the other PCI-E port. However, that shouldn't matter because I have had those graphical glitches on the onboard card. This is what's so confusing. It can run perfectly for quite some time before it crashes... Only reset the cmos

Comment: What is a power stabilizing unit (voltage regulator?  UPS?)?  Most of the things you're looking at (and spending money on), wouldn't manifest in this way if they had a problem.  The most likely candidate is the wall power winking out.  A voltage regulator won't help that.  If you have a UPS, the battery may be dead or not connected.

Comment: @fixer1234 I do not know why people are so focussed on the power. The power's fine. With a power stabilizing unit I mean a good surge protector. The salesman told me it helped against my old house's iffy electricity (It'd blow out a lot of lamps)

Anyway, that was in an old house. The wall power winking out is not an option. My PC has this issue on every location and others do not have the issue using the same wall socket as I am. My PC also isn't the only device running on it, so I'd notice.

Comment: The symptoms you describe are consistent with the power winking out, which is why people are focused on the power.  A surge protector does nothing to protect from that.  It is a power company thing; the entire house would be affected, not a specific breaker.  It's a common "first world" occurrence, which is why UPSs are sold.  It's the likely cause and it's consistent with everything you cover.  Until you rule it out with a UPS, you're wasting your time and money testing and replacing all of those other things, which wouldn't produce the symptoms you describe.

Comment: @fixer1234 That's completely understandable, but it would not explain the graphical glitch and other phenomena. Also, with different locations I meant entirely different locations, not a different location within the house. Besides this, I'll say again that I would've noticed if that was the problem. My PC wouldn't be the only device getting problems from this. Everyone elses pc's should fail then, too. I don't waste money on replacing products (except my PSU). I wanted to replace them anyway. (My PSU was also already 8 years old)... It just can't be a power issue.

Comment: Fck me, guys... I was just random-reading and this actually got me wondering:
Could my power box (The one with the surge protector and such on it) actually be *the problem*? I just read somewhere that someone had a faulty search protector and had the same thing happening to him, albeit on a more regular basis (My pc hasn't crashed in 3 days now) -- For example, what if I'm simply putting too many watts on the thing and that triggers the surge protection, causing my pc to shut down because it's not getting enough power? The first time it started crashing was at a LAN party... Just thought of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it had to be one of these 3 things:

**The power supply**

I upgraded from 750W medium-quality to 850W top-quality.

**The VGA power cable**

Apparently, the r9 290 vapor-x draws sick amounts of power. (up to 372W) and the 2*8-pins power cable should apparently be meant twice. As in, the split-off second 8-pins from the first cable, apparently gives less power than the main one. This might have caused it.

**Most likely**

Sapphire told me my current Vbios (graphic's card bios) was unstable, and asked me to flash it.

--

either way, the problem seems to have been solved. This is just... really awkward. All my parts have been stresstested and spread out. My old PSU is working perfectly fine in a friend's new build, my old GPU is running fine in my brother's new build and my new card ran in it perfectly smooth as well (even though he had an even cheaper power supply), my motherboard, CPU and RAM all worked fine in someone else's build as well.

You'd almost think it was a very specific compatibility issue between my motherboard's BIOS and my GPU's BIOS. It's interesting at the very least. I seem to attract very non-standard issues. (Trust me, this is not the first issue I've had to defy all logic)
- note that I did get my graphics card, motherboard, cpu and RAM back. I didn't change my build!